# I trying to map the data from the database and getting this error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to map the data from the database and getting this error.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```
 import React from "react";
    
    export default class Allusers extends React.Component {
      state = {
        people: [],
      };
    
      async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "http://localhost:5000/dashboard/getuser";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ people: data.results });
      }
    
      render() {
        //const peopleJSX = [];
    
        //this.state.people.forEach((person) => {
        //peopleJSX.push(
        //<div key={person.id}>
        //<div>{person.firstname}</div>
        //<div>{person.lasttname}</div>
        //</div>
        //);
        //});
    
        return (
          <div>
            {this.state.people.map((person) => (
              <div key={person.id}>
                <div>{person.firstname}</div>
                <div>{person.lasttname}</div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

FYI my API is working I have tested it on Postman.

[This is the screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh5BA.png)

Comment: Do you see the correct value in your console.log ?

Comment: Please post the output of `data`. `data.results` appears to be `undefined`.

Comment: @BrianThompson I can view the data which is needed in the console.

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan yes I can see the correct values in console.log

Comment: @ShreyasAnilChaudhari How do you expect `data.results` to equate to `data.data.gigs`?

Comment: @ShreyasAnilChaudhari The screenshot you included shows an error in a different part of the code (a completely different component) than the one you included in the question. Furthermore, the data shown in the console doesn't correspond to what the code seems to be expecting.

Comment: @Lennholm I am sorry but I Posted the wrong screenshot, I have posted the new SS.

Comment: @BrianThompson Sorry, But I posted the wrong SC, now I have posted a link to the new SC of my error.

Comment: Ok but the follow up question is basically the same: how do you expect `data.results` to equate to `data.gigs`? There is no `results` key on that object?

Comment: @BrianThompson Thank you so very much I got it and got my required output. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the state inside of the constructor of the class like the example below:

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The code is from this example: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html.
Right now you just have a variable named state and it's not bound to the class.

Comment: It may be a better practice, and would be required if the state was initialized with `props`, but it is not required to put it in the constructor for it to work.

Comment: Also this statement *Right now you just have a variable named state and it's not bound to the class* is incorrect. `state` is a class property the way they have it defined.

Answer (score 0):

There is the correction in the above code.
Instead of:

```js
this.setState({ people: data.results });
```

Use:

```js
this.setState({ people: data.gigs });
```

as the gigs are the key of the object in which the data is stored.